# Firebase create Indexes automatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a real estate application where I want my users to be able to filter with almost all the properties my collection has. The collection has like 30 properties, like price, type, department, zone, number of rooms, and a bunch of booleans, and is not viable to create an index manually for each combination, it would take forever. Is there any way to create indexes automatically for all this combinations?

Comment: No. There is no way to automatically create indexes. One reason is that it might actually have a significant impact on the storage cost of your project. You will have to determine which combinations are possible, and create the minimal number of indexes needed for that. Note that not every query needs it own index, as the database can [merge existing indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging) for many queries.

Comment: Note that there is a limit of 200 composite index for one Firestore database. If you want to be able to filter and/or sort on 30 properties you might reach this limit very fast. You may change your data model or use the RTDB.

Comment: Hi, did you come up with a solution?